# only include file once in git repository

Tags: git

I have this file. let's say `x` for this example inside folder `y`. I want to put a stub in the directory(P.S: I believe [this github project](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/blob/master/examples/example_keys_file.js) does actually what I want to) , but only once. For this example it looks like this:

```
module.exports.id = "";
module.exports.secret = "";
module.exports.callback = "";
```

Those values should not be shared, that's why I only want to put the file(stub/empty) inside the repository once.

When I modify `x` again, changes should not be put in the git repository, but only inside directory `y`.

I hope I make sense and that this is also not a duplicate question. If that is the case I would love to know the stackoverflow topic which discusses this, so that I can close this topic.

Comment: Have you tried symlinks?

Comment: Ho do you mean actually? could you give an example please. Post it as an answer maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solve it the following way: I rename the file `x`to `x-default` and set git to ignore the file `x` (eg. by a `.gitignore` in the dir `y`). Every user who checks out the repo has to copy the checked out file `x-default` to `x` and set his values.

This has the advantage, that the file `x-default` can be updated with new values without problem (not overwriting the user's config) and because of `x` is ignored, the user's values do not get synced with other user's repos (like you want).

Your program should check for the existence of `x` and, if not there, give a hint to copy `x-default` to `x` and configure it (or do this automatically).

---

Edit

> This works, but I believe it can be done cleaner.

Depends on what you want. You can also use this on your local repo:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged x
```

So you commit the file once, and then run the command on the file if you do not want further changes to be commit. The problem here is, that other users will have to do the same once if they want to have it like you, or else their changes will get commited (and will overwrite yours or it will end in a merge conflict).

To undo this, just go

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged x
```

I'm not aware of an other solution, but maybe someone other.

---

Edit

> P.S: I believe this github project does actually what I want to

This more looks like my first answer! They have a file `example_keys_file.js` and in the file `.gitignore` they ignore `keys_file.js`.

Comment: This works, but I believe it can be done cleaner. I update my question to show reference to github why I bet uses this. Maybe I ask him by sending email.

Comment: I believe you are right about your bottom p.s part(oops :$). inside `examples/app.js` he instead uses `var example_keys= require('./keys_file');`. I guess I will accept your answer in a couple of hours if you don't mind. I would like to give it some more time to see if someone else has even a better solution.

Comment: well, no need to hurry to accept any answer - if there's a better solution i want to know it, too! But I cannot think of another one, because it would make things really complicated (having a file *just half* in a repo).

Comment: I think you are right about that. Else that other project might have used that solution also. But don't you agree with me that it would be cleaner if you did not have rename that file to use library? Just fill in those fields and get started.

Comment: it would not be cleaner because of the probably arising merge conflicts (eg. how should it be handled if you want to change the file sometime after you checked it in? what should happen on the other user's repo with that file they changed?). If you publish a file to the end user, you usually don't do this by a vcs. And then you can of course rename the file to the right name to publish it, so the user does not have to do it.

Comment: I like the fact that you can still update the template by creating an example file. It takes away the hassle if you want to update the file afterwards

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach to this problem is :

1. Put `template.ext.in` in your repository
2. Have your makefile/script/manually copy `template.ext.in` to `template.ext` and modify the values
3. add template.ext to your `.gitignore` to ensure it never gets committed.

Comment: Yup this could also work, but I believe it can be done cleaner because connect-auth contains this stub. P.S: I updated my question to have a reference to this to late :$.

Comment: That file referenced in `connect-auth` is under version control which means you're at risk to accidentally commit it after you modify. You can't have it both ways: either you do the work to copy a template or you risk an accidental commit.  `.gitignore` won't ignore a file that's already under version control.